# Using summarise_at with mean and multiplying the result R

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I need to summarize some columns by calculating the mean and multiply the result with 100.

This works:

```
test <- tibble(a = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5),
           b = c(0.33, 0.44, 0.42))
test %>% summarise(ma = mean(a, na.rm = TRUE) * 100,
                   mb = mean(b, na.rm = TRUE) *100)
```

```
     ma    mb
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    30  39.7
```

This also works:

```
test_2 <- test %>% summarise_all(list(mean), na.rm = TRUE)

test_2 * 100

   a        b
1 30 39.66667
```

But as I have a lot of columns, I don't like the first one. I would also like to do this all in a bigger pipe (so I don't like option number 2), so I would have hoped something like this would work:

```
test %>% summarise_all(list(mean * 100), na.rm = TRUE)
```

But it doesn't:

```
Error in mean * 100 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: With `dplyr` 1.0.0: `test %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~mean(.) * 100))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example

```
test %>% summarise_all(list(function(x) 100*mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Also, note that `summarise_all` has been superceded by `across` functionality in `dplyr` v1.0.0.